# focusout handler also fires on focusin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code that executes an AJAX request every time the text input is focused out. The thing I don't understand is when I focus back in the AJAX request gets executed. There's no focusin function defined. Code snippet below:

```js
 $(function() {
      // some other functions here but no focusin function defined.

      $( "#additem" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _id = "new_pn", _holder = "Enter part number here", btnId = "post", btnIcon = "fa fa-save", btnText = " Add Serial", formId = "new-sn";
        openModal(_id, _holder, btnId, btnIcon, btnText, formId);
      });

      var openModal = function(a,b,c,d,e, f) {
        var txtInput = $("#myModal form input")[1], btn = $("#myModal form button")[0], icon = $("#myModal form i")[0], form = $("#myModal form")[0];
        txtInput.id = a;
        txtInput.placeholder = b;
        btn.id = c;
        icon.className = d;
        form.id = f;
        $($("#myModal form span")[1]).text(e);
        $("#myModal").attr('style', 'display:block');
      };

      //Check serial before saving when text field is focusout. 2nd argument, #new-sn is a dynamically created form id.
      $('#myModal').on('focusout', $('#new-sn input')[0], function() {
        var sn = $("#serial").val();
        if (sn) {
          Promise.resolve(GetDocumentItems(serialsDb, sn)).then(function() {
            console.log(sn.toUpperCase() + " already exists in the database");
          }).catch(function() {
            console.log(sn.toUpperCase() + " is cleared to save in database.");
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here? Cheers

Added HTML code below:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!--variable form id (depends on the caller)-->
    <form>  
      <div class="container">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <input id="serial" type="text" placeholder="Enter serial number here">

          <!--2nd text box, variable id and placeholder (depends on the caller)-->
          <input type="text"> 
          <!--button variable id and i variable class (invoker dependent).-->
          <button class="green"><i></i> <span></span></button>
       </div>
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `focusout` event may be bubbling up from a different element than you expect as the event handler seems to be bound to the container. Difficult to say exactly without seeing the HTML

Comment: can you post the HTML too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you're right. It is definitely bubbling to the 2nd input field inside `#myModal` container. Removing the 2nd input field inside the form solves the problem. How can I use the `.on` call here? I can't use the input text `id` directly as a selector as I don't want to fire the `focusout` event if the form id is different. I've tried `event.stopPropagation()` right after the event handler but it's not working. Cheers

Comment: Try changing `[0]` in the selector to `.first()`

Comment: Tried `$('#new-sn input')[0]`,  `$('#new-sn input').first()`, and `$('#new-sn input:first)` but to no avail.`focusout` still fires on both `input`.

Comment: Just to add, even changing the form id in the html, `focusout` event still fires with the selector, `$('#new-sn input')[0]`.

Comment: Never mind guys. I managed to find a workaround on my problem. Adding an `if condition` on the form id sorted it out. It's just interesting though that regardless of the selector you provide, the `focusout` event still triggers. It seems that it will only matter on the delegated target you provide i.e. `$('delegated-target').on()`. There's a lot of things to learn about jQuery. Cheers